# Apply CTE function consolidating strings to every row in a H2 table

Tags: sql, h2, common-table-expression

I have a table with long strings in one column which I want to consolidate into an easier to read format (`'abc;abc;abc;efg;hij;klm;klm;klm'` -> `'abc: 3, efg: 1, hij: 1, klm: 3'`).

I have written a function that consolidates the string, but now I want to apply it to every entry in a table. Any suggestion on how this can be achieved?

This is the code that splits and consolidates the string in `@str`:

```
SET @str = 'abc;abc;abc;efg;hij;klm;klm;klm;';

WITH   cte1(token, remainder) AS (
    SELECT LEFT(@str, LOCATE(';', @str)-1) AS token, 
        RIGHT(@str, LENGTH(@str)-LOCATE(';', @str)) as remainder -- anchor member
    UNION ALL
    SELECT LEFT(remainder, LOCATE(';', remainder)-1) AS token, 
        RIGHT(remainder, LENGTH(remainder)-LOCATE(';', remainder)) as remainder -- recursive member
    FROM   cte1
    WHERE LENGTH(remainder)>0 -- terminator
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT token, count(token) AS c
    FROM cte1 
    GROUP BY token 
    HAVING LENGTH(token)>0 
    ORDER BY token
)
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(': ', token, c) SEPARATOR ', ') FROM cte2 
    GROUP BY 1
```

The first `cte1` breaks the string into separate tokens, the second `cte2` creates a pivot and counts each instance, and the final `SELECT` statement consolidates the resulting table into one single string.

How would I apply this to each entry in column `S1` in the following setup, e.g. by updating the table and adding the result into `S2`?

```
    CREATE TABLE T1 (
ID INT, S1 VARCHAR, S2 VARCHAR);

INSERT INTO T1 
    VALUES  (1, 'abc;abc;abc;efg;hij;klm;klm;klm;', ''),
            (2, '123;123;235;235;235;987;987;123;', '');
```

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: If you're already doing some consolidation work, why not do it the proper way and create a separate table pointing to id from original table and having rows for each word with their usage count? I think you're overcomplicating your SQL life unnecessarily

Comment: @KamilG. - not quite sure what you mean. I get the data in the table with the long string, and I would like to apply the consolidation function on each entry. Whether I have it in a second table or the original is not so important.

Comment: What I mean is for you to change your output requirement. Instead of doing what you described I'm proposing a different, in my opinion, better solution. I can elaborate in an answer if you are in charge of how database looks like and can perform these changes.

Comment: @KamilG. - thanks a lot, but I did not design the DB, I am only a consumer, so unfortunately there is nothing I can change about it. I agree that there would be much better ways to design this.